# jQuery ajax requests as Deferred - wrap fail callbacks

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred, abort

My web-app has all its ajax calls in the form

```
$.post(url, data, successCallback).fail(failCallback)
```

My need is to introduce a mechanism of abort if some circumstances occur.

Since calling .abort() also triggers the failCallback, I'm trying to figure out a way (if any), to intercept the abort failure and do not trigger the callback.

Comment: could add a property to the xhr object when you call abort, and check for that property in fail callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't thing you really can do that, when the `abort` is called, the ajax request fails, and the fail method is called.

The closest I think you'll get is checking the error and calling the function conditionally, as aborting will throw `abort` as the error (and as status)

```
$.post(url, data, successCallback).fail(function(xhr, status ,err) {
   if (err !== 'abort')
       failCallback();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/f3ob2Lrt/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply (and thanks @charlietfl too), i was afraid this wasn't possible.. I found a few solutions but all assuming to use the `error` property in the ajax configuration. My failCallbacks are all specific to their very own request (so it's not one for all), but i guess i'll convert (or wrap) them to include the `abort` check.

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that the `.abort()` method is only (naturally) available on jqXHR promises. Such promises propagate through `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()`, but *not* through `.then()`, which is guaranteed to issue a new promise.